# Spring Data Neo4j - Unable to download 2.1.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, neo4j, sbt, spring-data-neo4j

I'm using Play! 2 framework using SBT for dependencies.
I want to retrieve 2.1.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT version for [Spring Data Neo4j](http://www.springsource.org/spring-data/neo4j#maven)

My `ApplicationBuild.scala` (used by SBT) is the following:

```
import sbt._
import Keys._
import play.Project._

object ApplicationBuild extends Build {

  val appName = "webapp"
  val appVersion = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

  val appDependencies = Seq(
    jdbc,
    anorm,
    "org.springframework" % "spring-aop" % "3.2.0.RELEASE",
    "org.springframework" % "spring-aspects" % "3.2.0.RELEASE",
    "org.springframework" % "spring-beans" % "3.2.0.RELEASE",
    "org.springframework.data" % "spring-data-commons-core" % "1.4.0.RELEASE",
    "org.springframework" % "spring-expression" % "3.2.0.RELEASE",
    "org.springframework" % "spring-jdbc" % "3.2.0.RELEASE",
    "org.springframework" % "spring-orm" % "3.2.0.RELEASE",
    "org.springframework" % "spring-test" % "3.2.0.RELEASE",
    "org.springframework" % "spring-tx" % "3.2.0.RELEASE",
    "org.springframework.data" % "spring-data-neo4j" % "2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT" excludeAll(
        ExclusionRule(organization = "com.sun.jdmk"),
        ExclusionRule(organization = "com.sun.jmx"),
        ExclusionRule(organization = "javax.jms")
      ),
    "org.neo4j" % "neo4j" % "1.8.1",
    "asm" % "asm-all" % "3.1"
  )

  val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies).settings(
    scalaVersion := "2.10.0",
    resolvers += "TAMU Release Repository" at "https://maven.library.tamu.edu/content/repositories/releases/",
    resolvers += "Spring Maven SNAPSHOT Repository" at "http://repo.springsource.org/libs-snapshot"
  )

}
```

All dependencies are well downloaded except **spring-data-neo4j**.

It leads to this error:

```
warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::                                        
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: org.neo4j#neo4j-cypher-dsl;1.8.RC1: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.neo4j#neo4j-cypher-dsl;1.8.RC1: not found
```

Is it normal that `neo4j-cypher-dsl;1.8.RC1` is not found?
What should I do to retrieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround:

Adding:

```
resolvers += "Neo4j Cypher DSL Repository" at "http://m2.neo4j.org/content/repositories/releases"
```

will download the missing jar.